# How reliable is the Eclipse update mechanism

Tags: java, deployment, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, updates

We need to enable our users to launch an Eclipse RCP application which will connect to a server. The user should not need to install anything besides a JRE. And the application must always be updated to the newest version.

Since Java Webstart advertises solving all our problems, we currently use it. But starting with 7u25 we had a lot of trouble with this, and our application even refused to work with 7u45.

This is the reason I am thinking about another deployment strategy, which is also used by google chrome: If you are going to http://chrome.google.com, you are not asked to download a zip or even exe file and then leave the browser to manually install chrome. Instead (on Windows) the installer is directly launched. This installer is even intelligent enough to recognize if chrome is already installed and does not request admin rights again and just starts the browser.

I plan on implementing a similar installer with Java. The installer would still be launched using Webstart, but would only install a small Eclipse core, which than would automatically install the rest using the Eclipse update mechanism. Because of this the webstart launcher might not change at all for some time, reducing a lot of the trouble we have with webstart.

But is the Eclipse update mechanism capable of reliably updating an Eclipse RCP application even if we for example change the base from juno to kepler? Or will we need to uninstall the client on major version changes, leading to an even worse situation compared to webstart?

Answer (score 1):

WebStart is now considered a security risk and I think needs all downloads signed with traceable certificate (no self signing).
I'm not sure about major / minor versions either, but you need to configure your RCP app to check for updates on start up by default. Create a file `plugin_customization.ini` in the plugin with your branding and add following contents:

```
org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP = true
# check for updates on startup
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/enabled=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/schedule=on-startup

# remind the user every 4 hours
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/remindOnSchedule=false

# download updates before notifying the user
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/download=true
```

Comment: Still need to check. At the moment we have to implement Webstart though, because our customer wants it.

Comment: You can also take a look at Eclipse Project Oomph, an installer for development environments. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Installer